# Ansible role post tasks

Tags: ansible

Is it possible to have "post tasks" in a role? i.e tasks defined in a role, that would run at the end of the play?

For example, I have a `common` role, which most other roles depend on. The `common` role provides some basic stuff to avoid repetition, such as tweaks to yum config, etc.

I notice that [playbooks have `post_tasks`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_roles.html#roles). I was wondering if it is possible to define post tasks in roles themselves?

---

**Update:**
Quoting the [Ansible documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_intro.html#handlers-running-operations-on-change):

> ## Handlers: Running Operations On Change
>
> ...
>
> These ‘notify’ actions are triggered at the end of each block of tasks
>   in a playbook, and will only be triggered once even if notified by
>   multiple different tasks.
>
> ...
>
> Roles are described later on. It’s worthwhile to point out that
>   handlers are automatically processed between ‘pre_tasks’, ‘roles’,
>   ‘tasks’, and ‘post_tasks’ sections.
>
> ...

Evidently this part of the documentation is either misleading, or down right lying (=there is an error in it). It appears that handlers are fired **at the end of each play**, between the `tasks` and `post_tasks`, as this following simple test shows:

```
- name:         Handlers test
  hosts:        all
  gather_facts: no
  roles:
    - some-role
    # some-role depends on common
  tasks:
    - name:  This a task
      shell: /bin/true
  post_tasks:
    - name:  This is a post task
      shell: /bin/true
```

And the common role:

```
# tasks/main.yml

- name:   Registering handler
  shell:  /bin/true
  notify: this is a handler


#handlers/main.yml

- name:   this is a handler
  shell:  /bin/true
```

(Since nobody provided an answer I can't accept one, but didn't feel right answering my own question with tips from the comments...)

Comment: how closely does a `handler` fit what you are looking for?

Comment: A handler will run between the `roles` and `tasks` section of a playbook. I need something that runs after the `tasks` section, i'e like `post_tasks`.

Comment: `handler`s run after everything if there is a trigger.  It sounds like you expect them not to fire after `tasks`, but they do.

Comment: Right, handlers run at the very end.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand - a handler defined and triggered in a role would run before or after the `tasks` section of the top-level playbook?

Comment: OK just tested it and apparently the documentation is lying...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is caused by a bug in Ansible 1.9.x, it's currently tracked here: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/12575